# Google Cloud Print set Page Orientation with Intent Data

Tags: android, printing, google-cloud-print

Implemented Google Cloud Print (https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/android) and working fine. **To print the page in landscape orientation I've to set the option manually**.

My requirement is to **set the orientation automatically via intent**. This is possible with PHP code as given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18523827/206809.

Not sure how to do the same with Android.